# cocos2d: since iOS 7.1 the haligment of CCLabelTTF broken when i switch my phone to hebrew

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

since iOS 7.1 i have the haligment of CCLabelTTF broken when i switch my phone to hebrew. (it's always aligned to the right no matter what)
When my phone is in english it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing:

```
[string drawInRect:drawArea withFont:uifont lineBreakMode:linebreaks[lineBreakMode] alignment:alignments[hAlignment]];
```

in CCtexture2D.m

to:

```
/// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
/// Set line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = linebreaks[lineBreakMode];
/// Set text alignment
paragraphStyle.alignment = alignments[hAlignment];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: uifont,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:255
                                                                             green:255
                                                                              blue:255
                                                                             alpha:1.0f]

                              };

[string drawInRect:drawArea withAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: tried to submit and issue https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/issues/653 but got ignored.